# Уточнение или продолжение мысли

Tags: запятые, уточнения

У меня есть сложности с определением уточняющей части предложения, если она не выделена запятыми.
Вот пример такого предложения:

Действует 1 раз в течение 5 дней на доставку от минимальной суммы, при самовывозе и в магазине — без неё, не работает со скидками и акциями.

Стоит ли поставить запятую:

Действует 1 раз в течение 5 дней (,) на доставку от минимальной суммы, при самовывозе и в магазине — без неё, не работает со скидками и акциями.

Буду благодарна за упрощённое объяснение правила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такие уточнения, точнее, добавления не характерны для делового стиля (объявления, инструкции). То есть такие, какие можно и не делать. Вам же не нужна стилистическая ошибка.

Уточнение — это когда переход от широкого к узкому. При нём можно вставить "а именно". Но здесь нет широкого. Какое же слово мы уточняем? Но можно сказать что-то вдобавок — следующей фразой (добавление).
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4

"*От минимальной суммы*" — что-то здесь не так.

Comment: Простите, но я не совсем вас поняла :( Вы считаете, что запятая здесь неуместна?

Comment: Ну да. Если не объявление/инструкция, а кто-то кому-то говорит, то ещё можно поставить (тогда пауза).

Comment: "Без неё" надо в скобки, а если деловой стиль, то вообще убрать.